# JavaScript: Sort array elements where "truthy" field values come first

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects where each has a property called `field`. Some values of the `field` properties are truthy:

```js
const arr = [
  {field: true},
  {field: false},
  {field: false},
  {field: true},
  {field: true},
  {field: false}
]
```

I want to sort this in such a way that all elements of field `true` must come first. How can I do that?

Currently  my code looks something like this:

```js
arr.sort((x, y) => x.field) // ??
```

Comment: So what is problem in your current code>/

Comment: It doesn't work. The array is not sorted, it is left just as I declared it.

Comment: Why say "truthy" and give all boolean values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to use `Array#sort` and return a sort key of `-1` or `1` explicity which would achieve the desired result:

```js
const array = [
  {field: true},
  {field: false},
  {field: false},
  {field: true},
  {field: true},
  {field: false}
]


/* Return -1 for sort key when item field value
is truthy bubbles that item to top of the sorted
array. Return 1 pushes item to bottom of sorted
array */
array.sort(item => item.field ? -1 : 1);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take the delta of the boolean values. Because of `true` is one and `false` is zero, you need to reverse the values.

```js
const array = [{ field: true }, { field: false }, { field: false }, { field: true }, { field: true }, { field: false }]

array.sort((a, b) => b.field - a.field);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `sort` should a number so you can subtract the `field` property of the objects.

```js
 

const arr = [
  {field: true},
  {field: false},
  {field: false},
  {field: true},
  {field: true},
  {field: false}
]
arr.sort((a, b) => b.field - a.field);
console.log(arr)
```